# Issue regarding Ad Mob Interstitial ads

Tags: android, admob

I was given a project with a pretty substantial user base. Earlier in the year we received a violation from Google regarding "interstitial ads out of app". The original code was loading the ads in the onAdLoaded method of the listener.

We ultimately decided to remove the interstitial ads for the time being and pushed an update. I was surprised to receive another email saying that we violated in the same manner. I had a crazy theory that one of the older app versions is possibly causing the violation. Support is refusing to answer any questions and says they have no more information. We've got roughly 300,000 users split up between three older versions that have that bad ad code.

Is this a crazy theory? If so, what are my options? The only thing I can think of at the moment would be to kill the offending interstitial ad id, then generating a new one for the updated app.

Comment: When do you display the ad?

Comment: We display it between breaks in the application, say navigating from a detail activity to main screen.

Comment: That's fine, usually this happens when a developer shows the interstitial directly after app launches or when "exiting" the application. You can read this post for more info - https://www.google.com/amp/s/instapage.com/amp/interstitial-ads

Comment: I understand, but Google keeps flagging us and removing it from the store. I can't replicate it to verify. I removed all interstitial ad code and published a new app.. it still happened.

Comment: Then it must be from an older version. Perhaps creating a new ad id would be your only option. By doing that will cause ads not being shown to users that has the older version installed.

Comment: That's the information I tried to get from Google. Is this common that an older version can cause these issues? I can create the new one and republish. My worry is that unless I kill the interstitial ad-unit, that the old ones will continue to violate.

Comment: It's not common, but it is Google, expect anything. If you create a new ad id the older one will stop displaying. You can test this by creating a demo app. I've done the same in the past.